# How can you store a mouse position?

Tags: java, mouseevent

I'm trying to write an if statement that does stuff if the mouse is still. I am trying to accomplish this through point

```
Point storedPosition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

if (storedPosition == currentMousePosition){
 // do things when mouse is still
} else {
 // do things when mouse is moving
}
```

What Point could I use to get the currentMousePosition

Comment: What do you mean `mouse is still` ?

Comment: when the mouse doesnt move/remains stationary

Comment: Use a MouseListener (or similar construct depending on your GUI library) and a GUI-compatible timer such as a Swing Timer of a Swing GUI. Re-start the timer whenever the mouse listener (or MouseMotionListener if Swing) is triggered.

Answer (score 4):

If I am able to get it right you're trying to Check if mouse location has changed from the previous check.

```
private static void checkMouseLocation() {
    PointerInfo info = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    // This can sometimes be null, so check for it (e.g. when Windows' UAC
    // screen is active)
    if (info == null) {
        return;
    }
    Point currentLocation = info.getLocation();

    if (lastLocation != null && !lastLocation.equals(currentLocation)) {
        lastMoved = System.currentTimeMillis();
        triggerActivity();
    }
    lastLocation = currentLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do polling for something like this but rather since you're likely using an event-driven GUI library use events:

- Start a GUI-compatible timer such as a Swing Timer if this is a Swing GUI
- Use a mouse listener of some type (a MouseMotionListener if Swing) and in the listener, stop the timer and re-start it if it registers mouse movement.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen mouse-moving events, that come from Operation System.
[JNativeHook library](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) can help you to register the listener.
[Here](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Mouse) is the example of such listener.
In the body of such listener you can trigger any code, that need when mouse is moving/dragging